# How to implement a concurrent circular ticker (counter) in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, counter, atomic

I want to implement a circular counter in Java.
The counter on each request should increment (atomically) and on reaching an upper limit should roll over to 0.

What would be the best way to implement this and are there any existing implementations?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're that worried about contention using either CAS or `synchronized` then you could consider something more sophisticated like the proposed JSR 166e `LongAdder` ([source](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/LongAdder.java?view=markup), [javadoc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166edocs/jsr166e/LongAdder.html)).

That's a straightforward counter with low contention on multithreaded access. You could wrap that to expose (current value mod max value). That is, don't store the wrapped value at all.

Comment: How would you implement atomic rollover to zero with `LongAdder` ?

Answer (score 22):

It is easy to implement such a counter atop `AtomicInteger`:

```
public class CyclicCounter {

    private final int maxVal;
    private final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public CyclicCounter(int maxVal) {
        this.maxVal = maxVal;
    }

    public int cyclicallyIncrementAndGet() {
        int curVal, newVal;
        do {
          curVal = this.ai.get();
          newVal = (curVal + 1) % this.maxVal;
        } while (!this.ai.compareAndSet(curVal, newVal));
        return newVal;
    }

}
```

Comment: I wonder if this would really be atomic if thread looses priority between 
```this.ai.get()``` 
and 
```} while (!this.ai.compareAndSet(curVal, newal));```

Answer (score 12):

With Java 8

```
public class CyclicCounter {

    private final int maxVal;
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public CyclicCounter(int maxVal) {
      this.maxVal = maxVal;
    }

    public long incrementAndGet() {
        return counter.accumulateAndGet(1, (index, inc) -> (++index >= maxVal ? 0 : index));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the modulus operator, you could just increment and return the modulus.  Unfortunately the modulus operator is expensive, so I encourage other solutions where performance is important.

```
public class Count {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();
    private static final long MAX_VALUE = 500;
    public long getCount() {
        return counter.get() % MAX_VALUE;
    }
    public long incrementAndGet(){
        return counter.incrementAndGet() % MAX_VALUE;

    }
}
```

You would have to solve the Long.MAX_VALUE case as well.

Comment: What do you do when `counter` exceeds `long`?

Answer (score 2):

I personally think the `AtomicInteger` solution is a little ugly as it introduces a race-condition which means your update attempt could "fail" and have to be repeated (by iterating within the while loop) making the update time less deterministic than performing the entire operation within a critical section.

Writing your own counter is so trivial I'd recommend that approach.  It's nicer from an OO-perspective too as it only exposes the operations you're allowed to perform.

```
public class Counter {
  private final int max;
  private int count;

  public Counter(int max) {
    if (max < 1) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(); }

    this.max = max;
  }

  public synchronized int getCount() {
    return count;
  }

  public synchronized int increment() {
    count = (count + 1) % max;
    return count;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The other problem I perceive with the while loop solution is that given a large number of threads attempting to update the counter you could end up with a situation where you have several live threads spinning and attempting to update the counter.  Given that only 1 thread would succeed, all other threads would fail causing them to iterate and waste CPU cycles.

Comment: You'll should also implement toString() if you think you'll ever want to print a Counter.

Comment: Performance wise the Atomic Integer seems to be faster. See https://gist.github.com/1245597

Comment: Adamski, all the while loop does is to provide the benefits we normally get from synchronization.  Your solution will have the same non-deterministic update time (from the standpoint of the caller).

Comment: @sheki: The test code you've referenced only times a single thread accessing the counter.  The real slowdown with the while loop approach is due to thread contention whereby several live threads end up competing and hence spinning in the while loop wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: @CPerkins: With my solution if multiple threads attempt to call increment() simultaneously I would hope that they would gain access in the order they blocked on the method call.  I don't think this is guaranteed by the language spec but I would hope a sensible VM implementation would use some kind of queue data structure.  However, as per my previous comment my main issue with the while loop solution is that you could end up with many live thread spinning and competing to update the counter, wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: @Adamski, I see your point.  I did think that the spec guaranteed sequential access (never really thought about it, just assumed that would be true), so that's an interesting thing to learn.  Your new edit about spinning is intriguing.  Seems like the relative speed would end up being a function of the number of threads wanting to simultaneously update it.  If I had access to a true multiprocessor machine, I'd very much like to test this.  Maybe I'll poke around a bit.

Comment: @CPerkins: Actually after speaking to my colleagues they seem to prefer the while-loop approach with the justification that compareAndSet doesn't cause any blocking (as it typically relies on a machine level "test and set" instruction).  The point was made that if thread contention does occur then there are bigger problems at hand, namely that the counter is not keeping up with the threads using it (which makes my point about spinning largely redundant).

Comment: @Adamski Fair enough.  Thanks again for the note about synchronization not guaranteeing order.

Comment: Not too important but, counter never being equal to max value. We would change as count = (count + 1) % (max + 1);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class to increment atomically. <strike>As for setting an upper bound and rolling back to `0`, you'll need to do that externally...perhaps encapsulating all this within your own wrapper class.</strike>

Actually, it appears that you can use [`compareAndSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20int%29) to check the upper bound, and then roll over to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

I have to create a similar circular ticker for a custom Akka Routing logic which had to be different than the default ones to avoid network overhead, since my logic is just to pick the next routee.

**Note:** Copied from the suggested Java 8 implementation:

```
import akka.routing.Routee;
import akka.routing.RoutingLogic;
import scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class CircularRoutingLogic implements RoutingLogic {

  final AtomicInteger cycler = new AtomicInteger();

  @Override
  public Routee select(Object message, IndexedSeq<Routee> routees) {
    final int size = routees.size();
    return size == 0 ? null : routees.apply(cycler.getAndUpdate(index -> ++index < size ? index : 0));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For highly-intensive circular counter incremented by multiple threads in parallel, I would recommend using `LongAdder` (since java 8, see the core idea inside `Striped64.java`), because it is more scalable compared to `AtomicLong`. It is easy to adapt it to the above solutions.

It is assumed that `get` operation is not so frequent in `LongAdder`. When calling `counter.get`, apply to it 'counter.get % max_number'. Yes, modulo-operation is expensive, but it is infrequent for this use-case, which should amortize the total performance cost.

Remember though, that `get` operation is non-blocking, nor atomic.

Comment: Does LongAdder have get method? Do you mean sum()? sum(), yes, is non-atomic, so wouldn't it pose a problem with rolling over upper limit to 0? Anyway, it's interesting to see *actual* implementation...

Comment: We are talking Java 8 here, hence you have to take into account how `AtomicInteger` changed from Java 7 to 8, basically get and add or add and get are done at the assembly level -`XADD`- which is explained here:
http://ashkrit.blogspot.com/2014/02/atomicinteger-java-7-vs-java-8.html

LongAdder is the wrong tool for this, because you need each sum every time you increment.

Comment: @GuidoMedina, How accurate is this blog you referred to? In Java 8 `sun.misc.Unsafe` accumulation methods still call `compareAndSwapInt/Long` methods. Maybe these CAS methods do not actually invoke CAS processor instruction, but these are `native` methods, so how can we be sure of all platforms; after all XADD is platform-specific instruction, is it not?

Comment: Is not platform specific, is JVM specific, prior to JDK 8 it was done in two steps where starting from JDK 8 and forward it is done in a single CPU atomic op, Google "JDK 8 vs 7 XADD" and you will find something like this: https://ashkrit.blogspot.com/2014/02/atomicinteger-java-7-vs-java-8.html